# How to explain 21:98 which says that whatever is worshiped by the disbelievers will be in Hell fire?

Tags: quran, tafseer

> Certainly you ˹disbelievers˺ and whatever you worship instead of Allah
> will be the fuel of Hell. You are ˹all˺ bound to enter it. [21:98](https://quran.com/21/98?translations=20)

The unbelievers worshipped, besides idols, angels and Isa ibn Maryam. Please explain. Very necessary.

Comment: Thank you all so much for clarifying. I understood now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The verse says ما  (what) and not من (whom) , ما is *usually* used for inanimate objects like idols, and not for people. So Jesus عليه السلام and the angels are not included in the verse.
- The verse is general and Jesus عليه السلام and the angels are excluded from it by other verses of the Quran which promise protection from Hell fire for the believers who are innocent.

  > إذ قالت الملائكة يا مريم إن الله يبشرك بكلمة منه اسمه المسيح عيسى ابن مريم وجيها في الدنيا والآخرة ومن المقربين
  >
  > [And mention] when the angels said, "O Mary, indeed Allah gives you good tidings of a word from Him, whose name will be the Messiah, Jesus, the son of Mary - **distinguished in this world and the Hereafter** and among those brought near [to Allah].
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 3:45](https://quran.com/3/45?translations=20)</sup>

  The concept of specific exceptions in general verses exists throughout the Quran, for example in general the iddah is three menstrual cycles ([2:228](https://quran.com/2/228?translations=20)) but the case for a pregnant woman ([65:4](https://quran.com/65/4?translations=20)) is an exception to it , in general marriage with non-muslims is prohibited ([60:10](https://quran.com/60/10?translations=20), [2:221](https://quran.com/2/221?translations=20)) but Jewish women and Christian women are an exception to it ([5:5](https://quran.com/5/5?translations=20)).

**Ref:**

> وقال العلماء : لا يدخل في هذا عيسى ولا عزير ولا الملائكة صلوات الله عليهم ؛ لأن ( ما ) لغير الآدميين . فلو أراد ذلك لقال : ( ومن ) . قال الزجاج : ولأن المخاطبين بهذه الآية مشركو مكة دون غيرهم
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura21-aya98.html#qortobi)</sup>

> هب أنه ثبت العموم لكنه مخصوص بالدلائل العقلية والسمعية في حق الملائكة والمسيح وعزير لبراءتهم من الذنوب والمعاصي، ووعد الله إياهم بكل مكرمة
>
> <sup>— [Tafseer al-Razi](https://shamela.ws/book/23635/3993)</sup>

Comment: Excellent comprehensive answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Bismillahir Rahmanir Rahim. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidina wa Azimina, Wa Habibi Qulubina wa Shafii Nufusina, Abul Qasim Muhammad. Wa 'ala Ahli Bayti tayyibina tahireen.

---

The context this verse belongs to includes the verses 97-103.

> **97. And the Promise of the Truth shall draw closer, and then it make their eyes stare, those who are committing Kufr, ‘O woe be unto us! We
> have been in heedlessness from this. But, we were unjust!’**
>
> **98. You, and whatever you are worshipping from besides Allah, would be the fuel of Hell. You would be coming to it**
>
> **99. If they had been gods, they would not be coming to it, and they would all be in it eternally**
>
> **100. For them therein shall be sighing, and they would not be hearing therein**
>
> **101. Surely those for whom the good has preceded from Us, they would be remote from it**
>
> **102. They will not be hearing its slightest sound, and they would be in what their souls desire, for eternity**
>
> **103. The great terror shall not grieve them, and the Angels would meet them: ‘This is your Day which you were Promised’**
>
> [Quran 21:97-103 (page 49)](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/TafseerHub-e-Ali/CH21_SuraAlAnbiya_Verses51-112.pdf)

Following Hadith narration by Imam Muhammad Al-Baqir (as) explains it

> ‘From Abu Ja’far (asws) having said: ‘When this Verse was Revealed,
> the people of Makkah found intense abhorrence. So Abdullah Bin
> Al-Zab’ary came to them, and the Kafirs of Quraysh were engaged in
> discussion of this Verse. So Ibn Al-Zab’ary said, ‘Did Muhammad (saww)
> speak of this Verse?’ They said, ‘Yes’. He said, ‘If I was to
> acknowledge this Verse, I will oppose him (saww).
>
> So he included himself between them and he said, ‘O Muhammad (saww)!
> What is your (saww) view of this Verse which you (saww) recited just
> now? Is it regarding us and regarding our gods in particular, or
> regarding a community from the communities of the past and their
> gods?’
>
> He (saww) said: ‘But, (it is) regarding you all and regarding your
> gods, and regarding the communities of the past and regarding their
> gods, except the ones whom Allah (azwj) Excluded’.
>
> So Ibn Al-Zab’ary said, ‘I oppose you (saww), by Allahazwj! Isn’t
> praising upon Isa (as) better, and you (saww) have acknowledged that
> the Christians are worshipping Isa (as) and his (as) mother (as), and
> a group of the people are worshipping the Angels. So wouldn’t they be
> with the gods in the Fire?’
>
> So Rasool-Allah (saww) said: ‘No!’ So the Quraysh clamoured and
> laughed, and they said, ‘Your (saww) opponent Ibn Al Zab’ary (has
> defeated you)’. So Rasool-Allah (saww) said: ‘You are speaking the
> falsehood. But, I (saww) said: ‘Except the ones Excluded by Allah
> (azwj)’. And these are the Words of the Exalted: **Surely those for
> whom the good has preceded from Us, they would be remote from it
> [21:101] They will not be hearing its slightest sound, and they would
> be in what their souls desire, for eternity [21:102]**’.
>
> He (asws) said: ‘The Words of the Exalted: **the fuel of Hell
> [21:98]** – They shall be thrown into it with a fling’.
>
> He (saww) said: ‘The Words of the Exalted: **they would be remote from
> it [21:101]**, means the Angels and Isa Bin Maryam (as)’’.
>
> [Tafseer Hub-e-Ali (pages 50-51)](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/TafseerHub-e-Ali/CH21_SuraAlAnbiya_Verses51-112.pdf)

Another verses from Quran that proves innocence of Jesus (as) are followings

> 116.And when Allah Said: “O Isa son of Maryam! Did you say to the people: ‘Take me and my mother as two gods from besides Allah?’” He
> said: ‘Glory be to You! It cannot happen for me that I should be
> saying what isn’t right for me. If I had said it, You would have Known
> it. You Know whatever is within myself and I do not know what is
> within Yourself. Surely You are the Knower of the hidden matters
>
> 117.I did not say to them except what You Commanded me with, ‘Worship Allah, my Lord and your Lord’, and I was a witness upon them for as
> long as I was among them. But when You Caused me to die, You were the
> Watcher upon them; and You are a Witness upon all things
>
> [Quran 5:116-117 (page 48)](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/TafseerHub-e-Ali/CH5_SuraAlMaida_Verses77-120.pdf)

**Conclusion**

Angels, Prophet Isa (as) and his (as) mother Maryam (as) are safe.

Comment: Thank you, brother, for the clarification